# while started the metro bunndler in the VS code terminal for Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, terminal

Once started the npm start on the react native path using expo go facing the error in the following descriptions:

**Error Description:**
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on Android...
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found:

May i install the android SDK path in vs code. It need to be install in which path.